# Всплытие информационного окна(infowindow) при наведении на многоугольник(polygon)

Tags: google-maps-api, события

Не работает правильно всплытие окна в цикле, при наведении на полигон в google maps. Данные подтягиваются с json. Вот кусок кода...

```
 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {   

    // Init polygons
    var polygonGroup = new google.maps.Polygon({
      paths: data[i].polygon,
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.35
    }); 

    polygonGroup.setMap(_map);        

   // Init polygons windows information
    var polygonInfo = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: data[i].polygonInfo
      });

    // Hover polygons
    polygonGroup.addListener( 'mouseover', function(){
      this.setOptions({fillColor: '#00FF00'});
      polygonInfo.setPosition(polygonCenter(this));         
      polygonInfo.open(_map);
    }); 

    polygonGroup.addListener( 'mouseout', function(){
     this.setOptions({fillColor: '#FF0000'});
     polygonInfo.close();
    });            
  }
```

data = [
          {"polygon":[array],"polygonInfo":"string"},
          {"polygon":[array],"polygonInfo":"string"}
         ]

**Проблема в том, что у меня для обоих полигонов всплывает одно и тоже окно, то которое последнее.** То есть data[1].polygonInfo.
Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем у меня проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Все дело в области видимости переменных javascript (scope). Для решения этой проблемы нужно использовать *замыкание*.